# How do i Cache DOM elements with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the following code snippet, do i need to cache $("#loading") in another object (lets call it JqueryDOMCache) or Backbone does this for me? I want to make the app performant as I have 300 odd DOM interactions.

```
        var BeforeApploadView = Backbone.View.extend({
               el : "#loading",
               render : function(){
                    $(this.el).show();
               },
               hide : function(){
                   $(this.el).hide();
               }
           });

        var App = (function($){
           var app = {};
           app.start = function(s){
                 var beforeLoadView =new BeforeApploadView();
                 beforeLoadView.render();
           };
           return app;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything special.  There are two reasons for this:

- As long as you still have a reference to your `BeforeApploadView`, then it has a reference to `el` so that it stays alive.
- The jQuery `hide` function does not remove the elmenet from the DOM.  It only applies `style="display: none"` to the element.  The DOM keeps a reference to the element as well.

You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks Brian, so each .render() call does not create a new jquery object? In that case, if I have multiple jquery calls in my render function, every object remains cached or just the top level object?

Comment: It does not create a new object.  There is no magic in the render function.  What you write is what you get.  So, the jQuery `show` simply takes the `display: none` style off the `el` that is already in the DOM.  No new element is created :)

Comment: Thanks Brian, going through the source backbone.js reveals a lot - like this...

// Element lookup, scoped to DOM elements within the current view.
// This should be prefered to global lookups, if you're dealing with
// a specific view.

  var selectorDelegate = function(selector) {
    return $(selector, this.el);
  };

Comment: I'd add that reading the annotated source is even better.  (you may already be doing this, but I thought I'd add it here for completeness) http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html